# QAudioSink triggers error QAudio::UnderrunError after a short while

Tags: qt, audio

I have a program that generates audio, but is incapable playing it, so it needs to pipe it's output to another program that plays it back.

So running this program via QProcess, I can use setStandardOutputProcess to pipe it to a second QProcess. This works fine.

But I wanted to eliminate the second QProcess as well as have more control over it, so I switched to using a QAudioSink to play back the audio instead, which works nicely.

But only for a short while, after which it starts to drop audio, or not play anything at all anymore, returning QAudio::UnderrunError, which indicates that audio data is not being fed to the audio device at a fast enough rate.

I've been trying setting buffer sizes, calling reset() after the QAudioSink goes idle, and quite a few other things.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]